# I can not show numbers(Quantity) in lightning datatable. All other fields are showing properly except number. Any solution please?

Tags: datatable, number

```
component.set('v.columns', [
            {label: 'Product Name', fieldName: 'Name', type: 'Text'},
            {label: 'Total Quantity', fieldName: 'Total_Quantity__c', type: 'number'},
            {label: 'Sold', fieldName: 'Sold__c', type: 'number'},
            {label: 'Available', fieldName: 'Available__c', type: 'number'},
            {label: 'Price', fieldName: 'Price__c', type: 'currency', typeAttributes: { currencyCode: 'BDT'}},
            {label: 'Category', fieldName: 'Category__c', type: 'Picklist'},
            {label: 'Sub Category', fieldName: 'Sub_Category__c', type: 'Sub_Category__c'},
            {iconName:'utility:picklist_type', type: 'action', typeAttributes : {rowActions:tablActions}}
        ]);
```

Here is the image for better understand

[image]

Comment: May be a dumb suggestion, but have you tried using `'Number'` instead of `'number'`?

Comment: Can you show how the datatable is displayed?

Comment: Dear @MattLacey, 
I also tried 'Number' type. But didn't work.

Comment: Dear @PrzemysławTamoń,
Here is the datatable looks like-
https://drive.google.com/file/d/18jtQcNcCz0wLTft3V7giECuxhr2-4D8s/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please edit your question and provide the image there

Comment: Dear @PrzemysławTamoń,
I've added the image with the code as you asked.

Comment: Have you checked field level security on those fields?